# Connection was not established. Probably 'xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal' is incorrect. Change 'xdebug.remote_host'

Tags: docker, phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

**I'm trying to use Xdebug (v3) through PhpStorm (v2022.3.2) to debug a PHPUnit test method from inside a Docker container.**

**Xdebug is correctly setup** and also the server in PhpStorm is.

In fact, if I run tests from command line, Xdebug stops at breakpoints:

```
XDEBUG_SESSION=1 PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=myapp.localhost" vendor/bin/phpunit --testdox --filter testProfileUpdate
```

If I debug the test clicking on the "bug" icon on the left of the test method, instead, I receive the following error:

> Connection was not established. Probably 'xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal' is incorrect. Change 'xdebug.remote_host'.

Looking at **the command executed by PhpStorm** to debug a test method, here is what I see:

```
[docker://myapp:latest/]:php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_port=9000 -dxdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal /opt/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /opt/project/phpunit.xml --filter "/(ProfileTest::testProfileUpdate)( .*)?$/" --test-suffix ProfileTest.php /opt/project/tests --teamcity
```

## Tried to configure two more flags

I've also **tried to configure two more flags**:

- `-dxdebug.idekey="serverName=myapp.localhost"`
- `-dxdebug.session=1`

The resulting command is this:

```
[docker://myapp:latest/]:php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_port=9000 -dxdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal -dxdebug.idekey="serverName=myapp.localhost" -dxdebug.session=1 /opt/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /opt/project/phpunit.xml --filter "/(ProfileTest::testProfileUpdate)( .*)?$/" --test-suffix ProfileTest.php /opt/project/tests --teamcity
```

Also with this configuration, Xdebug doesn't start and breakpoints are ignored (and the error message pops up).

## Tried to disable params passed by PhpStorm

I tried to disable params passed automatically by PhpStorm going to Settings > PHP > Debug.

Then, in the section "Advanced settings" I unflagged the option "Pass required configuration options through command line".

Now, the resulting command is this:

```
[docker://myapp:latest/]:php /opt/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /opt/project/phpunit.xml --filter "/(ProfileTest::testProfileUpdate)( .*)?$/" --test-suffix ProfileTest.php /opt/project/tests --teamcity
```

As you can see, there is no mention of `xdebug.client_host` nor of `xdebug.remote_host`.

Nevertheless, PhpStorm continues to pop up the same error mentioning `xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal`.

I imagined that an error should have occurred, but different, something saying a required parameter is missed.

## Request for help

**Any idea about how to configure PhpStorm to start an Xdebug session to debug a PHPUnit test?**

Comment: 1) Enable Xdebug log (`xdebug.log`), try to debug (when it's working and when it's not) and see what the log has to say (where it connects to, what the response is etc) 2) Would be good to see the actual/live Xdebug config -- show the output of `xdebug_info()`

Comment: 3) *"`-dxdebug.idekey="serverName=myapp.localhost"`"* -- as far as I get it this will not work / wrong approach. You are trying to pass it as Xdebug IDEKey param .. but it is actually should be the ENV variable named `PHP_IDE_CONFIG`. If you want to use it -- look into PHPUnit config file -- it has the ability to set up custom ENV for tests. The Run/Debug Configuration for PHPUnit has `Environment variables` field -- try using it for this purpose .. or in your actual docker file/config.

Comment: 4) *"`-dxdebug.client_port=9000`"* Xdebug 3 now uses 9003 port buy default instead of 9000. Try sticking to this. In PhpStorm you most likely have both ports listed (default value, to cover new and old Xdebug versions) and it uses the first one for CLI scripts (which PHPUnit is). Either remove it (only have `9003` there) or make it last (i.e. `9003, 9000`). That's in case if you use 9000 port in your Docker for some other needs (e.g. php-fpm also uses it, and that' the main reason why Xdebug now uses 9003).

Comment: @LazyOne, the problem was actually the port: it was set to "9000,9003": setting it to "9003" actually fixed the problem. Thank you!

If you write your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the right answer... thank you again!

Comment: `-dxdebug.idekey="serverName=myapp.localhost"`: @LazyOne, yes, it was just a try: I tried everything (but not all, as the evidence demonstrated) and that was a try based on "almost desperation" 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `-dxdebug.client_port=9000`

Xdebug 3 now uses `9003` port by default instead of `9000`. Try sticking to this.

In PhpStorm you most likely have both old and new ports listed (`9000,9003` as a default value) to cover new and old Xdebug versions. But it uses **the first in a list** for CLI scripts (which PHPUnit is)...

Either remove it (preferred; so you will only have `9003` there) or make it last (i.e. `9003,9000`). It's a per-project setting so you can use old 9000 port in another project if needed.

---

> `-dxdebug.idekey="serverName=myapp.localhost"`

This will not work (wrong approach). You are trying to pass it as Xdebug IDEKey param... but *it actually should be the value of the `ENV` variable named `PHP_IDE_CONFIG`.*

If you want to actually use it:

- Look into the PHPUnit config file: it has the ability to set up custom ENV variables for tests.
- Another place: PhpStorm's Run/Debug Configuration for PHPUnit has an `Environment variables` field: try using it for this purpose.
- Or use it in your actual docker file/config.

---

Other than that: enable Xdebug log (`xdebug.log`), try to debug (both when it's working and when it's not) and see what the log has to say for both runs (where it connects to, what the response is etc). You should spot the difference that should give the clues on what might be wrong (in which direction to dig further).

This actually should be the first step when investigating "why it works here and not there" situations.

Comment: Can confirm, fixed my issue when running tests from phpstorm with break points.

Comment: Port order fixed my issue aswell